# Encrypt root instance volume using luks ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, debian-jessie, luks

In need of encrypting the Instance root volume using **luks** on debian OS in AWS.

Is it possible to do that ? Help needed !!! Thanks in advance.

Please consider, I don't meant AWS encryption of root volume.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to do that for Ubuntu.
https://github.com/dzaninov/aws2luks

Maybe you can adjust it to work for Debian.